# Is it possible to have TeXWorks default to pdftex upon opening?

Tags: texworks

I have looked through TeXWorks settings and am not finding an option that appears to provide that functionality.

TIA.

Comment: Edit, Preferences, Typesetting, Default, pdfTeX

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

[image]

Preferences:

[image]

Typesetting:

[image]

Default: pdfTeX

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. Trying to get up to speed with MikTeX, as I am unsure how long PCTeX will still be viable, given that they seem to have gone dormant. I like PCTeX very much, but I think the writing is on the wall, so to speak.

Comment: @GrumpyAeroGuy MikTeX is very comfortable for my needs.  The `.gz` files that allow moving from the source code to the pdf output via CTL-<click> is a very nice feature.  The worst part is that highlight colors are not easily changed and, in some cases, are too pale by default.